# Can't delete the right one in the list

Tags: reactjs

Here is the code in the App.js

```
  const completeTask = (index) => {
    let itemsCopy = [...taskItems];
    itemsCopy.splice(index, 1);
    setTaskItems(itemsCopy);
  }
  var tasksArr = taskItems.map((item, index) => {
    return(
      <Todo key={index} text={item} title={index+1} completeTask={completeTask}/>    
    )
  })
```

And here is the Todo.js

```
function Todo(props) {
    return (
        <div className="todo-container">
            <h2 className="todo-title">{props.title}.</h2>
            <h3 className="todo-content">{props.text}</h3>
            <button onClick={() => props.completeTask(props.key)} className="todo-delete">Delete</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When everytime i click a delete button on the list, first one in the list is deleted. It seems like it doesn't know the right index number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use index as a key when mapping components that can be deleted, added, or updated.

Key should be unique to that item. If you set it as an index, and you delete the first todo in the list, all other todos will get a new key (React will think that todo 1 is now Todo 0, Todo 2 is now Todo 1, etc..) This code might remove the right item, but React will get confused as those keys get shifted for all todos.

The solution is to use unique keys like this:

```
const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([{id: 1, text: "My Todo"}, {id: 2, text: "My Other Todo"}])

const completeTask = (id) => {
    let itemsCopy = [...taskItems];

    //Find the index of that object with its id
    let index = itemsCopy.findIndex(x => x.id === id);

    itemsCopy.splice(index, 1)
    setTaskItems(itemsCopy);
  }

      var tasksArr = taskItems.map((item, index) => {
    return(
      <Todo key={item.id} id={item.id} text={item.text} title={index+1} completeTask={completeTask}/>    
    )
  })
```

And then in your Todo component

```
function Todo(props) {
return (
    <div className="todo-container">
        <h2 className="todo-title">{props.title}.</h2>
        <h3 className="todo-content">{props.text}</h3>
        <button onClick={() => props.completeTask(props.id)} className="todo-delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
)
```

I am not sure, but I think that you cannot even access props.key. You need to use your own ids. [Read more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: Thank you, one more question. How can i add to the taskItems? I'm currently using a state named 'task' and change it on text input. Then i add the task to taskItems. But your answer includes an array of objects, mine is only an array of strings

Comment: setTaskItems([...taskItems, {id: 5, text: "My new Todo"}]);

or
const myNewTask = {id: 5, text: My new Todo}
    setTaskItems([...taskItems, myNewTodo}]);
Or you can use a copy of taskItems like before and use Array.push()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push